# MVVM Structure: Where does sending a file to a server go in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am currently developing a WPF application to take in account credentials from the user and generate a csv file based on their account. The Model connects to the account using the credentials inputted from the View and collects the information needed. The code will then organize the information into a csv file and send it to a server.

My question is should I have the information uploaded to the server from the Model, ViewModel, or make a new View to upload to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual upload is undoubtedly a model function (ie, a "FileUploadService"). If you want to display progress or anything like that, a new View/ViewModel may be in order (due to separation of concerns).

For future reference, *any* crossing of a process boundary, and pretty much any logic that doesn't have to do with the UI, goes in model classes.

Comment: "any crossing of a process boundary, and pretty much any logic that doesn't have to do with the UI". - "Only the Sith deal in absolutes". Data access is crossing of a process boundary, and it is often in a separate layer from model (core logic)

Comment: @ASh Join the dark side :). Yes of course there are exceptions. If you want to say there's a 4th layer, ok. In MVVM you typically speak of just the three though. "Core" logic is in the model for me.

Comment: @ASh Everthing that is not the binding source for the view is model in MVVM. A model can consist of multiple layers. MVVM describes the archictecture in a more coarse way with the only intention to separate and decouple the view from the business logic (by using a binding mechanism). I would say the quoted statement is absolutely valid.

Comment: @BionicCode, *absolutely* valid? I might want to display some data, received from model, in a separate application, by launching some .exe file. It is crossing of process boundary for presentation purpose, of which model should not be aware

Comment: @ASh separate application? Sounds like something that should go through the VM to a service, and any answer back through the channel. Still goes in the "Model". Why would a view know anything about a separate application

Comment: @ASh Okay let's play it. First application communicates with a second application. Just because you say display I think it's clear that first application doesn't access the view directly. This application must expose an API e.g console args, SOAP, ... From OS perspective there are two processes. Maybe same machine, maybe different Tier. From application perspective they both are two services.

Comment: @ASh Does the view expose the API? No. Does the view model expose it? No. We are exchanging data between services. You wouldn't put database into the view model too, right? But it's also inter process communication from OS perspective. But database goes into the abstract model. Now here comes the point: MVVM has this dependency definition with unidirectional arrows pointing from view -> view model -> model, which means: user wants to see some data -> and tells view model via command which -> gets data from the model via `GetData()` or an `DataReady` event.

Comment: @ASh Model accesses database or service (which can be another application) and returns data. Now view model sends data to view via binding. Or your case: user wants to see some data -> and tells view model via command which -> view model knows it must use API and invokes a `void GetSpecialData()` (no value returned). Since the application depends on a second one to get the business done it's still business logic here just on a remote domain like ordinary multi Tier application. So model knows the data is on different server (or application) and uses its API.

Comment: @ASh API of other process doesn't return value because it raises an event to notify its own view model to update data properties which will update the view to display data. That's it, process kicked off by the model because the model extends cross domain, no different than communicating to a database server on a different machine in a different country. First application offers to display certain data (UI triggers a certain use case), then it is part of the application's business logic to serve or satisfy the use case. If a database is necessary or a second application(server) doesn't matter.

Comment: @ASh Business is domain of the model. It's not the view model that knows the business architecture, it's the model. Other application also uses MVVM or MVP or MVC: so model communicates with model. A service is always in a waiting state, waiting for an event so that it can serve. An exe that can take arguments to do some business must be designed like a service.

Comment: _"It is crossing of process boundary for presentation purpose, of which model should not be aware"_. Model A crosses boundary by comunicating with another model B of the other domain (via interface using a protocol). Model A doesn't know it's own presentation layer nor does it know the presentation layer of model B's domain. Model B doesn't know it either since it also implements MVVM. I think you tricked yourself by focusing on the word _display_ and _presentation_ instead on architecture. You ignored the fact that the other process is also designed to use a model (MMVM, MVP, MVC).